# LongListSelector and Image_MouseLeftButtonDown issue

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

How can I manage that the event LongListSelector_SelectionChanged run first, then Image_MouseLeftButtonDown run after that

```C#
int count = 0;
Image LastImage = null, curImage = null;
BitmapImage bi1 = new BitmapImage();
BitmapImage bi2 = new BitmapImage();
int itemIndex;

void getImageLink()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < CImageControl.lstImage.Count; i++)
     s.Add(CImageControl.lstImage[i].ImageLink);
}

private void lstView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var myItem = ((LongListSelector)sender).SelectedItem as CImage;
    itemIndex = ((LongListSelector)sender).ItemsSource.IndexOf(myItem);
    //MessageBox.Show(myIndex.ToString());
}
```

then this will run

```C#
private void Image_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    string lastImageSource, lastImageAltSource, curImageSource, curImageAltSource;
    count++;
    if (count % 2 != 0)
    {
        LastImage = (Image)sender;
        lastImageSource = s[itemIndex];
        lastImageAltSource = lastImage.Source.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        curImage = (Image)sender;
        curImageSource = s[itemIndex];
        curImageAltSource = curImage.Source.ToString();
    }
}
```

`ImageAltSouce` is the display of the image, and I wanted to replace with `ImageSource`. But I need `itemIndex` to find index of images in Longlistselector before I can change any source. Since the event Image_MouseLeftButtonDown occur first, so I cant do anything

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: im trying to replace ImageSource with ImageAltSource which is already displayed. All i need is to make sure event LongListSelector_SelectionChaned occur first, then it will be solved